# Full text search work for artist not for title

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match

I've a problem with full text search.
I've two tables:

Songs

```
+------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
| id_canzone | canzone               | id_artista | canzone   |
+------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
|        107 | Can U Believe         |         15 | I'm Sorry |
+------------+-----------------------+------------+-----------+
```

Artists

```
+------------+---------+
| id_artista | artista |
+------------+---------+
|         15 | Akon    |
+------------+---------+
```

If i search for artist with full text search i got no problems.

```
SELECT *,MATCH(artista) AGAINST('Akon Can U Believe.' ) FROM artists

+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| id_artista | artista | MATCH(artista) AGAINST('Akon Can U Believe.' ) |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
|         15 | Akon    |                             1.9237866401672363 |
+------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
```

But when i try with songs table

```
SELECT id_canzone,canzone,MATCH(canzone) AGAINST('Akon Can U Believe.' ) FROM songs

+------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
| id_canzone | canzone       | MATCH(canzone) AGAINST('Akon Can U Believe.' ) |
+------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
|        104 | Can U Believe |                                              0 |
+------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

I've reduced the ft min word len parameter, try to rebuild index. Nothing change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Mysql stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html).

Both "Can" and "Believe" are stopwords and "U" is too short, so your match will return 0.

If you want to use fulltext for searching music titles you have to modify your stopword list or disable it completely.

See [fulltext fine tuning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html) on how to do that.

When testing fulltext make sure you have enough rows in your table.
Words that are present in more than 50% rows are treated as stopwords despite your stopword custom settings.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Disabled stopword and it work perfectly!